# How can I read iso-8859-1 file

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface

I try to read  File.java file with iso-8859-1 encoding . I  executed command like this

iconv -f ISO-8859-1 FileSorter.java -t ASCII//TRANSLIT

but I still get some wrong characters after converting:

```
 /**
 * Yoio iaoia auiieiyao ni?oe?iaeo nienea oaeeia
 * @param fileList iaioni?oe?iaaiiue nienie oaeeia
 * @return ioni?oe?iaaiiue nienie oaeeia
 */
```

Any idea how can I read this characters

Comment: Without the original file for reference, one can only guess that it was not in the expected encoding.  A URL pointing to the file would fill in the necessary information.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Nj-vLTRyujWUlRMXNFOW5RejA/view?usp=sharing added link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is not ISO-8859-1.  That would be Western Europe.  Instead, it looks like one of the Cyrillic flavors (for example ISO-8859-5).  Here is a screenshot showing the file before converting it:

[image: viewing file using vi-like-emacs in koi8rxterm]

You would probably not like the result transliterated into `ASCII`.  I recommend converting it to UTF-8, e.g.,

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-5 FileSorter.java -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT
```